# Display multiple images in a single UIView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uiimageview, xcode4.3

I want the user to pick images from the camera library and they will be displayed in individual image views which is inside a single view application.  Any ideas, tutorial or code will be great.

Thank you

Comment: `GCC: Error: question.c:1:1: expected 'effort', found 'nothing'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent tutorial for what I think you're trying to do :) Couldn't write it simpler myself so might as well just link it.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/130/how-to-write-a-custom-image-picker-like-uiimagepicker